# Filling a region in the complex plane in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, implicit-conversion, complex-numbers

So I have plotted the the function defined implicitly by `fimplicit` in Matlab. I want to fill the region inside. How to do that?

```
f1=@(x,y) (1+x+x.^2-y.^2).^2+(y+2.*x.*y).^2-1;

fimplicit(f1)
hold on
axis([-1.5 0.5 -1.5 1.5])
xlabel('Re(h\lambda)')
ylabel('Im(h\lambda)')
hold off
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`fill`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html) with inputs given by the `XData` and `YData` properties of the `ImplicitFunctionLine` object produced by `fimplicit`:

```
f1 = @(x,y) (1+x+x.^2-y.^2).^2+(y+2.*x.*y).^2-1;
h = fimplicit(f1, 'linewidth', 1);
hold on
axis([-1.5 0.5 -1.5 1.5])
xlabel('Re(h\lambda)')
ylabel('Im(h\lambda)')
fill(h.XData, h.YData, 'b', 'FaceAlpha', .1)
```

[image]